# JavaScript: Calling a method inside a function outputs Undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm a newbie to JavaScript.I was experimenting with the object methods and invoke them with global functions. My question is : When I called the method inside a function,it outputs undefined at the end along with the answer.Why is that ?

```
function ShowMessage(msg)
{
    if(arguments.length == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<p><i>"+msg+"</i></p>";
    }
}

var obj = obj || {};

obj.property1 = "Hello1";    

obj.method1 = function(msg)
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +="<p><b>"+msg+"</b></p>";
}
var catalyst = obj.method1(obj.property1);
ShowMessage(catalyst);
```

output

```
Hello1 // in bold 
undefined // in italics
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything, use the `return` keyword and your function will now pass something back. You can return whatever you want, I don't know what you are expecting but that's the gist. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: That's because `method1` has no `return` statement, so `undefined` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions *can* return a value but by default they return `undefined`. For example:

```
function logSomething(){ console.log(arguments); }
```

`logSomething` returns `undefined` because there is no purpose to actually returning anything. The function will be called, but no one is asking what it has to say.

(If you would describe this function in other languages like C, you could define it as `func logSomething -> Void`, with the `->` indicating what the function will return and in this case it returns into the Void, which you can imagine being like shouting in outer space. You execute a shout, but no one will hear it.)

```
function multiply(a, b){ return a * b; }
```

`multiply` returns the value of mutliplying `a` and `b`. When calling this function, you *want* something to be returned. If you do `var c = multiply(2,3);` you *want* c to not be `undefined` but to be `6`. In our aforementioned space-shouting function you would actually *want* someone to hear you. This would be `multiply -> Int`)

In programming some functions are useful when they have a return value, others don't. If you don't define a `return` statement, then the returned value will default to `undefined`.

In your example you are modifying the DOM, you don't actually want a value to be returned, so when you log the outcome it will be `undefined`.

Have a look at the `return` statement documentation at MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
obj.method1 = function(msg)
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +="<p><b>"+msg+"</b></p>";
}
```

This does not return anything. The call

```
var catalyst = obj.method1(obj.property1);
```

will define a variable catalyst which is auto assigned nothing. This is passed to `ShowMessage`wich then prints "undefined" unsurprisingly.

Change:

```
obj.method1 = function(msg)
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +="<p><b>"+msg+"</b></p>";

    return msg;
}
```